# Dropbox File Management Alternative for Salesforce

Tags: files, file-storage

Trying to find an external file management app like Dropbox which is integrated with Salesforce. Unfortunately, Dropbox for Salesforce has some really bad reviews in Appexchange(2.7 rating :-( ). What products do other admins use as a substitute?

SO the scenario I'm trying to solve is that we're trying to get a single file management app that both non-salesforce and Salesforce users can use. For Salesforce users, the ability to upload files within Salesforce or to link files in the external to records on Salesforce would be really useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent project I've found box.com to be a fairly good alternative. As with dropbox there is a managed package available from the AppExchange which provides many of the 'basic' integration requirements and box.com provides a well-documented API which can be used to develop additional integration features from salesforce.com or any web-connected system.

One thing I would STRONGLY recommend though, whether using Dropbox, box.com, AWS or anything else, is to clarify the support level and determine whether it's adequate for the planned commercial usage. A provider may provide adequate or even excellent support for its own system but this does not necessarily mean they provide good (or even any) support for the AppExchange package.